# getting error into encrypt and decrypt data using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, cryptography

```
I am using this code for Encrypt and Dycrpt the data using asp.net .
```

**But i am getting the error:--**

```
**Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm**. 

here is a code:-

my .cs file is:-

public static class Encrypt_Decrypt
{
static Encrypt_Decrypt()
{

}
public static string EncryptString(string ClearText)
{

    byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearText);

    System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hanuservicestalknsolve");
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hanuservicestalknsolve");
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV),CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);

    cs.Close();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
private static string DecryptString(string EncryptedText)
{
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedText);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();


    byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hanuservicestalknsolve");
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hanuservicestalknsolve");
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateDecryptor(key, rgbIV),
    CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    cs.Write(encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.Length);

    cs.Close();

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

}
}
```

**Here is my aspx.cs code:**

```
 string eventi = Encrypt_Decrypt.EncryptString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem,     "name_of_post_id").ToString());
    string post = Encrypt_Decrypt.EncryptString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "compreq_eventid").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`SymmetricAlgorithm.IV`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The size of the IV property must be the same as the BlockSize property divided by 8.

I suspect you'll find that `rijn.BlockSize` is 128, so you should provide a 32-byte IV.

(It's not clear why your variable is called `rgbIV`, and you don't have any of the appropriate `using` statements. I hope you're not using a fixed IV and key in your *real* code, too... otherwise it's not providing much security.)

Answer (score 0):

@user3168616: Below is the corrected code that works.

The problem was with the length of the string that you have provided for Key and rgbIV
the length of the Key and rgbIV should be of 16 bites
the code to get the length of the string in bites

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop"));
```

Modified version of your code (only change is in the string length)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strText = "this is the string";
        string encryptedString = Encrypt_Decrypt.EncryptString(strText);
        Console.WriteLine(encryptedString);
        string decryptedString = Encrypt_Decrypt.DecryptString(encryptedString);
        Console.WriteLine(decryptedString);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class Encrypt_Decrypt
{
    public static string EncryptString(string ClearText)
    {

        byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearText);

        System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnop");
        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnop");
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);

        cs.Close();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
    public static string DecryptString(string EncryptedText)
    {
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedText);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();


        byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnop");
        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnop");
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateDecryptor(key, rgbIV),
        CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cs.Write(encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.Length);

        cs.Close();

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

    }
}
```